# AudioKit/AVAudioEngine Takes Too Long to Start

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audiokit, avaudioengine

I'm using AudioKit, which uses AVAudioEngine underlyingly. I have built an average-sized audio chain with some players, a microphone, sound effects, and mixers to satisfy my app's functionality. However, I noticed that whenever I initialize the chain and call `AudioKit.start()`, it takes quite long to finish. 2s on a real device without earphones, and 7s when I use bluetooth headphones. Can anyone advise me if this is normal, and how should I make it faster? It does not feel normal to take 7s to process...

Comment: any solution? i am looking at the same problem

Answer (score 0):

@nicholas,

Do you have an example project that you can post to GitHub? Are you initializing the AudioKit engine in its own class, or within `viewDidLoad` in individual ViewControllers?

Also, which version of AudioKit and Xcode are you using?

Thanks,

Mark